# What HTTP status code should I use for a GET request that may return stale data?

Tags: web-services, rest

The scenario is: I'm implementing a RESTful web-service that will act as a cache to entities stored on remote a C system. One of the web-service's requirements is that, when the remote C system is offline, it would answer GET requests with the last cached data, but flagging it as "stale".

The way I was planning to flag the data as stale was returning a HTTP status code other than 200 (OK). I considered using 503 (service unavailable), but I believe that it would make some C#/Java HTTP clients throw exceptions, and that would indirectly force the users to use exceptions for control flow.

Can you suggest a more appropriate status code? Or should I just return 200 and add a staleness flag to the response body? Another option would be defining a separate resource that informs the connectivity state, and let the clients handle that separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mark Nottingham's [caching article](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) he says

> Under certain circumstances — for example, when it’s disconnected from
>   a network — a cache can serve stale responses without checking with
>   the origin server.

In your case, your web service is behaving like an intermediary cache.

A representation is stale when either it's Expires or Max-age header has passed.  Therefore if you returned a representation with

```
Cache-control: Max-age=0
```

Then you are effectively saying that the representation you are returning is already stale.  Assuming that when you retrieve representations from the "System C" that the data can be considered fresh for some non-zero amount of time, your web service can return representations with something like,

```
Cache-control: Max-age=3600
```

The client can check cache control header for max-age == 0 to determine if the representation was stale when it was first retrieved or not.

Comment: All answer are valid, but this is the one I've considered to be most semantically aligned to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Simply set the Last-Modified header appropriately, and let the client decide if it's stale. Stale data will have the Last-Modified date farther back than "normal". For fresh data, keep the Last-Modified header current.

Answer (score 3):

I would return 200 OK and an appropriate application-specific response. No other HTTP status code seems appropriate, because the decision if and how to use the response is being passed to the client. I would also advise against using standard HTTP cache control headers for this purpose. I would use them only to control third-party (intermediary and client) caches. Using these headers to communicate application-specific information uneccesarily ties application logic to cache control. While it might not be immediately obvious, there are real long-term benefits in the ability to independently evolve application logic and caching strategy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are serving stale responses [RFC-2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.1.1) says:

> If a stored response is not "fresh enough" by the most
> restrictive freshness requirement of both the client and the
> origin server, in carefully considered circumstances the cache
> MAY still return the response with the appropriate Warning
> header (see section 13.1.5 and 14.46), unless such a response
> is prohibited (e.g., by a "no-store" cache-directive, or by a
> "no-cache" cache-request-directive; see section 14.9).

In other words, serving 200 OK is perfectly fine.